# Qt / C++ - Tracking all QList<QProcess>

Tags: c++, qt

I have read about connecting a QProcess to a signal slot but I'm a bit lost for how to achieve my own purpose with it.

Every QProcess is stored in a QList

Every QProcess needs to be removed when they expire, whether terminated by windows or otherwise.

Naturally I'd use a QObject::connect() to connect it's signal for dying and slot. But I don't know to tell it to give me the right information.

```
connect(process, SIGNAL(destroyed()), this, SLOT(ProcessEnd()));
```

Should tell me if it's destroyed. However, none of the signals ever notice if it's killed via windows or anything other than the app itself.

Comment: You probably have `QList<QProcess*>`, right? I would fix the topic one way or another, to avoid having invalid code in it.

Answer (score 6):

`destroyed()` is signal from `QObject`. This signal is emitted immediately before the object is destroyed, and can not be blocked, so it is not what are you looking for. `QProcess` has another signal `finished()`. Try this:

```
QList<QProcess*> proc;
for (int i = 0; i < proc.size(); ++i)
{
    connect(proc.at(i),SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),this,SLOT(someSlot(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
}
```

[From doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished):

> This signal is emitted when the process finishes. exitCode is the exit
>   code of the process (only valid for normal exits), and exitStatus is
>   the exit status. After the process has finished, the buffers in
>   QProcess are still intact. You can still read any data that the
>   process may have written before it finished.
>   If the process cannot be started, -2 is returned. If the process
>   crashes, -1 is returned. Otherwise, the process' exit code is
>   returned.

There are `QProcess::NormalExit` when all is ok and `QProcess::CrashExit` when program crashed. Documentation contains information about `ExitStatus` too.